# Save numpy ndarray to file with index to file

Tags: numpy

I have a large NumPy array, say 1000*1000.
I want to save it to a file with each line format like the following.

`row col matrix[row,col]`

I can't seem to find a method that does it efficiently.

I could do a nested `for` loop but it's too slow.

Constructing a larger matrix which contains the indices would be too expensive on memory.

I was thinking of list comprehension, but are there other ways of doing it?

Comment: So this is supposed to be a text file (csv)?  Writing a text file isn't "efficient".  `savetxt` iterates on the rows of the arrays, formatting and writing one row at a time.  However you do it, writing 1,000,000 lines is going to be slow.  You could experiment with a smaller shape, trying different mixes creating individual points and creating larger matrices.  I don't think it will matter much.

Comment: IIUC you want multiple rows of "row col value". If your matrix is not sparse, your proposed saving format is  extremely inefficient, even more if you save it as text file.

Comment: Yes, I know it is highly inefficient. However, I have to link programs written in different languages, and that seems to be the easiest way.